# D3.js Multi Line Charts with zoom on y-axis and brush(as slider) on x-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm using D3 to create a realtime multi line charts with zoom and brush function. Basically I have two charts with their own zoom function for zooming in y-axis, and one brush function (work as slider) to control both x-axis.
The brush is working fine, however the zoom is not. When I zoom the 1st chart,  both of the line will change accordingly (which I only want to zoom the 1st line) and when I zoom the 2nd chart, only the y-axis is zooming.

**In another word, both of the lines are somehow linked with the y-axis in the 1st chart.**

Please find the simplified code example here:http://jsfiddle.net/rzhu1140/x8gL6yc7/5/

I really don't know what part of the code is wrong, please let me know anything you guys can think of. Thanks a lot. The code for data assign and drawing is below.

```
zoom.y(y);
g2_zoom.y(g2_y);
svg.select("path.line").attr("d", line);
svg.select("path.line").data([seriesData[0]]);
g2_svg.select("path.line3").data([seriesData[2]]);
g2_svg.select("path.line3").attr("d", line3);
svg.select("g.y.axis").call(yAxis);
g2_svg.select("g.y.axis3").call(yAxis3);
```